# MySQL select a list of users from a table grouped by projects, listed in descending amount of hours

Tags: php, mysql, select, max

I have a time sheet table such as this:

```
CREATE TABLE time
    (`id` int, `hours` float(1), `project` varchar(55), `user` varchar(45));

INSERT INTO time
    (`id`, `hours`, `project`, `user`)
VALUES
    (1, '3.5', 'Project A', 'Bob'),
    (2, '1', 'Project A', 'Anne'),
    (3, '2', 'Project B', 'Anne'),
    (4, '6', 'Project B', 'Anne'),
    (5, '2', 'Project C', 'Joe'),
    (6, '9', 'Project C', 'Joe'),
    (7, '1', 'Project C', 'Sam'),
    (8, '22', 'Project A', 'Bob');
```

and I would like to return a table such as this:

```css
th {background-color:#999999}
td {width:200px}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>User 1 (most hours)</th>
    <th>User 2 (2nd most hours)</th>
    <th>etc....</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tr>
  <td>Project A</td>
  <td>Bob</td>
  <td>Anne</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Project B</td>
  <td>Anne</td>
  <td>null</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Project C</td>
  <td>Joe</td>
  <td>Sam</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As it shows, I need to list who has spent the most time on each project in descending order. I believe I need to do a SELECT from a subquery, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT project, user
FROM time
GROUP BY project, user
ORDER BY SUM(hours) DESC
```

This would give the following result set based on the example data in your question:

```
--------------------
|  project  | user |
--------------------
| Project A | Bob  |
| Project A | Anne |
| Project B | Anne |
| Project C | Joe  |
| Project C | Sam  |
--------------------
```

Note that total hours worked by each user on each project is not listed, since you didn't ask for that.

Comment: Thank you, that is very close to what I need. Is there any way to show only one project per line and add the additional users in columns? Or even limit each result to only show the MAX user for each project would work.